# ReactJS and Websockets : Listening to server broadcast emit events on Frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, websocket

I am coding a chat application using `ReactJS, Socket.io, and NodeJS`. I have completed the basic socket connection part and when I enter a message and press enter the message is emitted to the backend. Now I want that once anyone adds a message (multiple tabs) the message gets broadcast to all the other clients except the one who initiated it and should be displayed in the messages list. I am broadcasting the message to all the clients from the server when the message is received from a particular Client, but not sure as to where to catch it on my frontend in react application.

Let me go through the code :

**App.js** - My app has 3 main components i.e. Users(Users list), Messages(Messages list that will display all the messages for all online users) and AddMessage (Contains and TextBox and button to add a message)

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {/* <UserNameInp /> */}
        <section className={classes.usersSection}>
          <Users />
        </section>
        <section className={classes.messagesSection}>
          <section className={classes.messagesStyle}>
            <Messages />
          </section>
          <section className={classes.addMessageStyle}>
            <AddMessage />
          </section>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**actions.js** : Stores addMessageToList actions. When a new message is added I emit it to the server using socket.emit

```
export var addMessageToList = messageText => {
  let messageDtls = {};
  messageDtls.messageText = messageText;
  messageDtls.messageAuthor = "You";  //just for testing
  messageDtls.messageID = "You" + messageText;  //just for testing
  socket.emit("addmessage", messageDtls);

  return {
    type: actionTypes.ADD_MESSAGE_TO_LIST,
    payLoad: { messageDtls: messageDtls }
  };
};
```

**reducer.js** - The reducer contains messagesList as a state value which contains all the messages from all the users including current.

```
var initState = {
  messagesList: []
};

var addMessageToList = (state, action) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    messagesList: [...state.messagesList, action.payLoad.messageDtls]
  };
};

var reducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.ADD_MESSAGE_TO_LIST:
      return addMessageToList(state, action);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default reducer;
```

**Messages.js** - The component renders each Message component using map as a list. The messagesList comes from redux store.

```
class Messages extends Component {
  render() {
    let messages = null;
    messages =
      this.props.messagesList &&
      this.props.messagesList.map((ele, index) => {
        return (
          <Message
            key={index}
            messageAuthor={ele.messageAuthor}
            messageText={ele.messageText}
          />
        );
      });

    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Card className={classes.card} raised={true}>
        <span>Messages</span>
        <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>{messages}</CardContent>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

var mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    messagesList: state.messagesList
  };
};

var mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    addMessageToList: messageText =>
      dispatch(actions.addMessageToList(messageText))
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withStyles(styles)(Messages));
```

**AddMessage.js** - The component in which action addMessageToList is dispatched on Button click so that message can be added in messagesList state.

```
class AddMessage extends Component {
  state = {
    value: ""
  };
  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    });
  };

  onEnterKeyPress = event => {
    this.props.addMessageToList(this.state.value);
    this.setState({
      value: ""
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Paper className={classes.root} elevation={1}>
        <InputBase
          className={classes.input}
          placeholder="Message"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.value}
          // onKeyPress={this.onEnterKeyPress}
        />
        <IconButton
          className={classes.iconButton}
          aria-label="Enter"
          onClick={this.onEnterKeyPress}
          disabled={this.state.value === "" ? true : false}
        >
          <ChatIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}

var mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    addMessageToList: messageText =>
      dispatch(actions.addMessageToList(messageText))
  };
};

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withStyles(styles)(AddMessage));
```

**Backend App.js** - An extract from App.js file where on connection with the socket I listen to 'addmessage' event and broadcast emit 'messagesadded' event.

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("User connected");
  socket.on("addmessage", message => {
    // messagesRecieved = message.messageText;
    console.log("Message received : " + message.messageText);
    socket.broadcast.emit("messagesadded", message);
  });
});
```

Now I am not sure where in my React code should I listen to 'messagesadded' event broadcasted from the server. It should be like a continuous listening so that whenever a message is being transmitted I can dispatch addMessageToList action again and it will update the messagesList state and render the Messages component again.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to the socket event in `componentDidMount()`.

```
componentDidMount(){
 socket.on("messagesadded", message => {
  //dispatch action
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. componentDidMount() of which component ? I tried it already in Messages but it is kind of never-ending dispatch. Moreover, my concern is if I listen to it in any of the components componentDidMount() method, for that to call the component must have been mounted over n over. What if the user types in a message and then sits idle and on another window, the user types in and the message are transmitted from the server, the componentDidMount() will not automatically trigger.

Comment: @ShantanuTomar in yoru **Messages.js** file. You can refactor you code by converting some components to stateless components. and keep the **Messages.js** as your state-full component.  You can validate the input (in add message component). Dispatch the send message only when you click enter on press send button then this wont be an issue.

Comment: I am sorry, but it's not clear to me. Messages is still a stateful component. And I am not sure how AddMessage component comes into picture here. Please if you can elaborate it, would appreciate that.